# Why the Pen tool is not filling properly?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, path

Working with photoshop, I've noticed that at really small size the pen tool filling is not so sharp when required to attach to a path/shape border:

[image]

As you see I have used pen tool aiming at guides, the handle is correctly placed on the guide perimeter, however the fill color is not starting from the shape border but a little shifted on the right/bottom.

Any idea on how to make the filling more precise?

Comment: That rectangle is ~6 pixels wide, not much you can do about it other than make a bigger rectangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quides are arbitarily placed, but all fills are pixels. You have placed the quides between pixel borders.

ADDENDUM: I have here a stroked path. It has been drawn along the quides. The 1 px wide stroke has been taken its place at the nearest pixels.

[image]

In Photoshop you must be ready for 1 px ambiquities until you fill pixels individually and watch the result on a display that show actual pixels as is or integer times enlargened

Comment: the document is measured in millimeters, I needed to make a small rectangle 0,5mm wide and it is not matching with the pixel, how can I do?

Comment: @Ritardi.Net exact fit needs total number of pixels/ the wanted width. But is that really a problem? The path is exact, only the shown filligs are made of the current pixels. They will be different as soon as you zoom the image into normal onscreen watching size.

Comment: scaling down the image from 290x290 pixel to 60x60 also produce some odd results, in particular small gaps such as the above (im subtracting from a shape with that rectangle) gets filled with "shades" of nearby pixels. Since I'm designing a geometric logo, what is the best approach to be able to design it in normal size while also being able to scale it down preserving its look?

Comment: @Ritardi.Net  Scaling down without changing the look: 60 is not an integral part of 290. No way to keep the looks. You will get heavy anti aliasing blur if you use smooth scaling such as bicubic. Nearest neighbour method make plusminus 1 pix errors. If it were 300pix instead of 290, all 5 pix areas would transform perfectly.

Comment: I can do 300x300 will this allow me to make a section of 60 while preserving it? I also noticed that the blur is more strong on horizontal gaps rather than vertical. I have another gap of 60 height horizontally which has even more blur

Comment: @300x300 reduces to 60x60 by integer 5 (=20%)  Only 5, 10, 15, 20... etc pixels wide or high detais stay intact. Design it as 60x60 if you need it so small and still geometrically perfect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59365/discussion-between-ritardi-net-and-user287001).

Answer (score 2):

You can't fill part of a pixel, only whole pixels. A pixel is the smallest unit of a raster image that can be edited.

If you fill your background with a colour, you will see the pixel grid when you zoom in.  Use these to place your guides/paths.

[image: Screenshot - Guides/Paths match pixels]

If you want six pixels across to measure 0.5mm, then you will need to set the resolution setting to 120 Pixels Per Centimetre.

120 pixels per centimetre = 12 pixels per mm, therefore 0.5mm = 6 pixels